# Select radio button on change select list and vice versa using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, radio-button, onchange

The radio buttons and select list contain the same values. I need to select the corresponding radio button if the select list changes and vice versa.

I have come this far, but I am having a hard time combining these functions... any help greatly appreciated.

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq9k87ce/)

```js
$('.select-color').change(updateRadio);

function updateRadio() {
    var sval = $(this).val();
    $('input[name="color"][value="' + sval + '"]').prop('checked', true);
};

$('input[name="color"]').change(updateSelect);

function updateSelect() {
    var rval = $('input[name="color"]:checked').val();
    $('.select-color' + ' option[value="' + rval + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    $('.select-color').selectmenu('refresh');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="color" class="select-color">
    <option value="1" selected>Red</option>
    <option value="2">Green</option>
    <option value="3">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="1" checked="checked" /> Red<br />
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="2" /> Green<br />
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="3" /> Blue<br />
</form>
```

*** Update ***
After I switched to using the Bootstrap Select plugin, I needed to update the code provided by @JoshCrozier. For those interested, here it is:

```
function updateElements(e) {
    var valueAttribute = e.target.value;
    $('select[name="color"]').val(valueAttribute);
    $('.select-color').selectpicker('refresh');
    $('input[name="color"]' + valueAttribute).prop('checked', true);
}
$('select[name="color"], input[name="color"]').change(updateElements);
```

Comment: So everything works, you just want to reduce the code?

Comment: Exactly as Josh mentions in his answer below. I was having a hard time combining it into one function (see alternative example), but the first solution is even cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to the `change` event of both elements using:

`$('.select-color, input[name="color"]').change(updateElements);`.

Then just get the triggered element's value using `e.target.value`.

```
function updateElements(e) {
    var valueAttribute = '[value="' + e.target.value + '"]';

    $('.select-color option' + valueAttribute).prop('selected', true);
    $('input[name="color"]' + valueAttribute).prop('checked', true);
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ma1c4h/)

```js
$('.select-color, input[name="color"]').change(updateElements);

function updateElements(e) {
    var valueAttribute = '[value="' + e.target.value + '"]';
    $('.select-color option' + valueAttribute).prop('selected', true);
    $('input[name="color"]' + valueAttribute).prop('checked', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="color" class="select-color">
        <option value="1" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Blue</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="1" checked="checked" />Red
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="2" />Green
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="3" />Blue
    <br />
</form>
```

---

Alternatively..

Though this would make the function a little longer, you could also add a little conditional logic to determine whether the triggered element is a `select`/`radio` like this:

```
function updateElements(e) {
    var $element = $(e.target),
        valueAttribute = '[value="' + $element[0].value + '"]';

    if ($element.is(':radio')) {
        $('.select-color option' + valueAttribute).prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        $('input[name="color"]' + valueAttribute).prop('checked', true);
        $('.select-color').selectmenu('refresh');
    }
}
```

[**Alternative Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/oeov01e5/)

Comment: I was working on the alternative example, but couldn't get it to work as I didn't target the elements correctly. But the first solution is even simpler!